# How to stop Custom cell contain strong label from overwriting the contents?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

the Problem is when using strong label type :KILabel to can detect @ and #.

after the cell number 10 it keep the value of cell 1 and 11 and so one 2 and 12

it over write the text on each other.

I know the problem from dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier but how can solve it the rest of feel controls working well just this label.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CommentCell *cell;
    CommentsModels * mycomment = [_CommentsModelsArray  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if([mycomment.CommentType  integerValue] == 2)
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CommentCellImage"];
    }else{
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CommentCell"];


    }
   // CommentCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CommentCell"];

    if (!cell)
    {


        if([mycomment.CommentType  integerValue] == 2)
        {
            [ tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CommentCellImage" bundle:nil]forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CommentCellImage"];


            cell = [ tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CommentCellImage"];
        }else{
            [ tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CommentCell" bundle:nil]forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CommentCell"];


            cell = [ tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CommentCell"];
        }




    }
    cell.commentimage.image = nil;
    [cell setcell:[_CommentsModelsArray  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.commentsViewController = self;
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    return cell;
}
```

the setcell function

```
- (void) setcell:(CommentsModels*)comment{


    User *user = [[HelpManager sharedHelpManager] applicationUser];

   UserId = user.userId;


    _generalcomment  = comment;


    if ( _generalcomment.Comment.length > 0) {
        KILabel *label;
        label = NULL;
        label = nil;
       label = [[KILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(76,66, 180, 14)];


                label.taggedUsers = comment.TaggedUsers;
        NSString *labelText = _generalcomment.Comment;
        for (TaggedUser *user in comment.TaggedUsers) {
            NSString *replacedText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(@%@)%@",user.UserName,user.FullName];
            NSString *tagText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@",user.UserName];
            labelText = [labelText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:tagText withString:replacedText];
        }
        label.text = labelText;
        label.tag = 1010;
        label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
        label.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        label.automaticLinkDetectionEnabled = YES;
        label.linkDetectionTypes = KILinkTypeOptionUserHandle | KILinkTypeOptionHashtag;
        label.userHandleLinkTapHandler = ^(KILabel *label, NSString *string, NSRange range) {
            TaggedUser *selectedUser = nil;
            for (TaggedUser *user in comment.TaggedUsers) {
                if ([string containsString:user.UserName] &&  [string containsString:user.FullName]) {
                    selectedUser = user ;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (selectedUser) {
                ProfileViewController *profileViewController = [STORYBOARD instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProfileViewController"];

                profileViewController.ProfileUserId = selectedUser.Id;

                if ( self.commentsViewController != nil)
                {
                    [self.commentsViewController.navigationController pushViewController:profileViewController animated:YES];
                }
                else{
                    [_postandCommentsViewController.navigationController pushViewController:profileViewController animated:YES];
                }

            }
        };




        label.hashtagLinkTapHandler = ^(KILabel *label, NSString *string, NSRange range) {
            SearchMasterViewController *searchMasterViewController = [STORYBOARD instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SearchMasterViewController"];
            searchMasterViewController.searchText = string;
            if ( self.commentsViewController != nil)
            {
                [self.commentsViewController.navigationController pushViewController:searchMasterViewController animated:YES];
            }
            else{
                [_postandCommentsViewController.navigationController pushViewController:searchMasterViewController animated:YES];
            }

        };


        label.urlLinkTapHandler = ^(KILabel *label, NSString *string, NSRange range) {
            // Open URLs
            [self attemptOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:string]];
        };

        [label adjustFrameSize];
       [self.contentView addSubview:label];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because dequeueReusableCell function return old cell that contain old label

so You can remove label before load new item.

```
- (void) setcell:(CommentsModels*)comment {
    [[self.contentView viewWithTag:1010] removeFromSuperview];
    //... your cuttom code here
}
```

Comment: @danh yes but in simple case like add or remove label, it will not make difference in performance. Your answer is good, I vote it :)

Answer (score 2):

The code has a few problems.

1) register the nibs when you're setting up views, as early as viewDidLoad

```
// in the view controller that is the table's datasource
// assumes you have an outlet setup in IB to the table view

@property(weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

// ...

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CommentCellImage" bundle:nil]forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CommentCellImage"];
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CommentCell" bundle:nil]forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CommentCell"];

    // plus whatever else you do in viewDidLoad
}
```

2) next, you can simplify and modernize your cellForRowAtIndex as follows

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CommentsModels * mycomment = [_CommentsModelsArray  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSInteger type = [mycomment.CommentType intValue];
    NSString *identifier = (type == 2)? @"CommentCellImage" : @"CommentCell";

    CommentCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.commentimage.image = nil;
    [cell setcell:[_CommentsModelsArray  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.commentsViewController = self;
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    return cell;
}
```

3) Lastly, the `setcell:` should factor out the label creation and only create the label conditionally, if the cell doesn't already have one (after the first display of the table, all of the cells will).

```
// in CommentCell.m

- (UILabel *)theLabel {

    KILabel *label = (KILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1010];
    if (!label) {    // only create one if its not there
        label = [[KILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(76,66, 180, 14)];
        label.tag = 1010;
        // everything else you do to create the label goes here,
        // but NOT anything variable relative to the model, so
        // for example, not label.text = anything

       [self.contentView addSubview:label];
    }
    return label;
}
```

Now `setcell:` is slightly saner, just getting the (probably already created) label and changing things about only that change for the given model item at the given row.

```
- (void) setcell:(CommentsModels*)comment {
    User *user = [[HelpManager sharedHelpManager] applicationUser];
   UserId = user.userId;
    _generalcomment  = comment;

    if ( _generalcomment.Comment.length > 0) {
        KILabel *label = [self theLabel];
        NSString *labelText = _generalcomment.Comment;
        // I didn't try to understand the following code, but it looks
        // potentially too slow for configuring a table view cell.
        // consider doing this calculation just once and caching the result in the model
        for (TaggedUser *user in comment.TaggedUsers) {
            NSString *replacedText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(@%@)%@",user.UserName,user.FullName];
            NSString *tagText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@",user.UserName];
            labelText = [labelText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:tagText withString:replacedText];
            [label adjustFrameSize];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much really appreciated

Comment: Happy to help.  That solution you marked correct, while quicker to code, fails to solve a very basic problem in the OP.   Imagine the user scrolling your table back and forth.  That same label setup code will run over and over, every time a cell scrolls into view, then you'll remove the label (according to that solution) and do it all over again.